# How do I get the expression for the Killing form of $\mathfrak{u}(2)$?

Tags: lie-algebras, cartan-geometry

I saw in the book of Mark Hamilton "Mathematical of gauge theory" in the pag. 126 that the killing form to lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}(2)$ is

$$B(X, Y) = 4 Tr(XY) - 2 Tr(X)Tr(Y).$$
I want prove this for this case (not the general case $\mathfrak{gl}(2, \mathbb{C})$). I am trying take the basis $(T^0, T^j) := (i Id, i\sigma_j)$, where $\sigma_j$ are Pauli's matrices, then, by one hand, a matrix $A \in \mathfrak{u}(2)$ can be write as

$$A = \frac{Tr(A)}{2i} T^0 + a_j T^j.$$
So,

$$ad(A) = \sum_{j=1}^{3} a_j ad(T^j),$$
because $ad(T^0)=0$. But, when I use the definition

$$B(A,B) := Tr(ad(A)ad(B)) =  \sum_{j=1}^{3} \sum_{l=1}^{3} a_j b_l Tr(ad(T^j)ad(T^l)),$$
I don't get progress, and seem to me that the $Tr(A)$ won't appear because the $T^0$ componente don't appear. Can anyone help me?

Appreciate.

Comment: You don't want to use the general case of $\mathfrak{gl}(2)$? Anyway, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3867273/let-l-gln-mathbbc-show-that-the-killing-form-on-l-is-given-by-ka?noredirect=1&lq=1) is the proof (or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135567/computation-of-the-killing-form-of-mathfrakgl-m?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Comment: the formula you give is for $\mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb R)$, not $\mathfrak{u}(2)$. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form

Comment: @DietrichBurde i don't understand the connection between the formula for $\mathfrak{gl}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathfrak{u}(n)$.. which one has the formula in the question? i believe if an algebra a is a subalgebra of b, a inherits b's killing form, is that correct? but is this the case here? we have different fields, no? thanks a lot for any clarification. cheers from Italy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote with $\{t_1,t_2,t_3\}$ a basis for $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ such that $[t_i,t_j]=\epsilon_{ijk}t_k$ (implicit sums over repeated indices will be assumed whenever suitable; I'll also not distinguish between lower and upper indices). Note that, in terms of the Pauli matrices, these are $t_i=-\frac{i}{2}\sigma_i$.

1. ***(First method)*** The Killing form is defined as $B(X,Y)={\rm Tr}({\rm ad}(X)\circ{\rm ad}(Y))$, for $X,Y\in\mathfrak{su}(2)$ with decompositions $X=X_i t_i,Y=Y_i t_i$.

   We have
   $$({\rm ad}(t_i)\circ{\rm ad}(t_j))(t_k) =
   [ t_i, [t_j, t_k]] =
   \sum_{\ell m}\epsilon_{jk\ell} \epsilon_{i\ell m} t_m =
   \sum_{\ell m}\epsilon_{jk\ell} \epsilon_{m i\ell} t_m.
   $$
   We can now use the identity
   $\epsilon_{jk\ell} \epsilon_{m i\ell} =
   \delta_{jm}\delta_{jk} - \delta_{ji}\delta_{km}$, to obtain
   $$({\rm ad}(t_i)\circ{\rm ad}(t_j))(t_k) =
   \delta_{ki} t_j - \delta_{ji} t_k.
   $$
   For the trace, you need to take the $t_k$ term in this expression, and then sum over $k$:
   $${\rm Tr}({\rm ad}(t_i)\circ{\rm ad}(t_j))
   = \sum_k (\delta_{ki}\delta_{jk} - \delta_{ji}) = -2 \delta_{ij},$$
   and thus
   $$B(X,Y)\equiv {\rm Tr}({\rm ad}(X)\circ{\rm ad}(Y)) =
   \sum_{ij} X_i Y_j {\rm Tr}({\rm ad}(t_i)\circ{\rm ad}(t_j)) =
   -2\sum_{i} X_i Y_i.
   $$
   If you represent $X,Y$ as matrices in the standard way, then
   $${\rm Tr}(XY) =
   \sum_{ij} X_i Y_j \left(-\frac{1}{4}{\rm Tr}(\sigma_i \sigma_j)\right) =
   -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i} X_i Y_i.
   $$
   We conclude that
   $$B(X,Y) = 4{\rm Tr}(XY).$$
2. ***(Another method)*** We can also leverage the general expression of the Killing form in terms of the structure coefficients. If $[t_i,t_j]=\sum_k {c_{ij}}^k t_k$, then $B(t_i,t_j)=\sum_{mn} {c_{im}}^n {c_{jn}}^m$. In the case of ${c_{ij}}^k=\epsilon_{ijk}$, as is the case for $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, we get
   $$B(t_i,t_j) =
   \sum_{mn} \epsilon_{imn}\epsilon_{jnm} =
   - \sum_{mn} \epsilon_{imn}\epsilon_{jmn} =
   -2\delta_{ij},$$
   and the rest follows as before.

A more general discussion about deriving the Killing forms for the classical Lie algebra is found in [How to derive the general formula for the Killing form for classical Lie algebras?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2578195/173147).

Comment: hi, is this the formula for $\mathfrak{u}$ (as for the question) or $\mathfrak{su}$? also, what is the connection between the Killing formula for $\mathfrak{u}$, $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$? thanks a lot, I am looking at  this and other related question and I am a bit confused. I have also left a comment in the question.